# R function does not returns values for date period

Tags: r, datetime

Here is function:

```
getData<-function(startDate, endDate, index, dateFrequency){
  hedge<-read.csv("f1.csv", header = TRUE)
  Date <- as.Date(hedge$Date, format='%m-%d-%Y')
  hedge <- cbind(Date, hedge[,-1])

  sD <- as.Date(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
  eD <- as.Date(endDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

  if (dateFrequency == "monthly"){
    query <- paste0('select HFRIEMNI from hedge where Date between "',sD,'"', ' and "', eD, '"')
    writeLines(query)
    d <- sqldf(query)
  }
  result <- d
  return(result)
}
```

Here is `f1.csv` file:

```
Date,HFRIEHI,HFRIEMNI
10-20-2000,-3.34%,1.23%
10-21-2000,2.85%,1.23%
10-22-2000,5.67%,0.82%
10-23-2000,-0.87%,0.73%
10-24-2000,5.92%,0.50%
```

After execution of function using this command:

```
getData("2000-10-20","2000-10-22", "HFRIEMNI","monthly")
```

I got 0 rows, nothing return, however I have values within this period.

Can you help me, what I am doing wrong? I can't solve this problem last 3 years.

Comment: I guess you got a reason to use SQLlite? I'm not very familiar with it. However, `hedge_ <- transform(hedge, Date = as.numeric(Date)); sqldf(paste0('select HFRIEMNI from hedge_ where Date between "',as.numeric(sD),'"', ' and "', as.numeric(eD), '"'))` works for example.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change query to this line:

```
query <- paste0("select HFRIEMNI from hedge where Date between ", as.numeric(sD)," and ",as.numeric(eD) )
```

Comment: SQLite has no date type so when the data frame is sent to SQLite the dates are converted to numbers (no of days since epoch) but then the code in the question is trying to compare those number to character strings.   The above answer converts eS and eD to numeric so it is all consistent.  Another way to do this is:: `query <- fn$identity("select HFRIEMNI from hedge where Date between $sD and $eD")`   Note that sqldf also supports the H2 database and it does have true dates so this type of problem would not exist if you use that.  See the sqldf home page and help files for more info.